# Subscribe a web app to an event in NServiceBus

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I would like to know how my web application can subscribe to an event from a server ? I know that a web app must not publish event. In the async sample, it is the web app that SEND message to the server. I want that the app SUBSCRIBE to the server. In others terms, how to handle an event from a web app.
I don't know how to write the Global.asax page :
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication and the void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) method.
Thanks in advance,
Loïc

Comment: Hi Loic you need to be clearer about what you want to do. I can see no logic in what you are asking. What event does your web app need to subscribe to? It sounds like your solution is not architecturally optimal. If you could clarify what you want to do, preferably separated numbered in some way, I would be happy to help you.

Comment: Well, I would like to implement this scenario, for example :
- a server publish (or send) a message : "a new user is registrered"
- a web app subscribe/receive the message and add this message in a database
- when I reload the web app witch show me the content of the database, I can see the message.
Is it possible using NServiceBus ?

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to have to disagree with Hugh.  There are very valid reasons for a web application to subscribe to an event published by another service.

Usually, it's not the kind of thing you want to take database action on.  A prime example use case would be for cache management.  Using your UserCreated example from the comments, the web application could respond to UserCreated by dropping its User object from the cache.  This helps multiple web applications working as part of a web farm to stay in sync with each other.

A more adventuresome use of a web application subscribing to an event (again UserCreated as an example) would be to create an ultra-scalable login service that never has to query the database to authenticate the user.  On startup, the web application would load all usernames and password hashes into a dictionary in memory, and then subscribe to a UserCreated event by adding to that dictionary.  It would likely also subscribe to a UserPasswordChanged event, in order to update that dictionary.

(It is important in that scenario not to think about caching an entire user object - this service would only be concerned with authentication, not authorization, and so only usernames and password hashes would be stored.)

In order to accomplish this, you have to set up the Bus yourself in the Global.asax as described in [Hosting NServiceBus in your own Process](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/).  The `.LoadMessageHandlers()` line is critical to having NServiceBus scan your website's assemblies for message handlers.

This is a typical fluent configuration block for a web application:

```
public static IBus Bus { get; set; }

// In Application_Start()
Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
        .Log4Net()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        .XmlSerializer()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
        .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .LoadMessageHandlers() // <-- only if handling commands/events
        .CreateBus()
        .Start();
```

Because web applications are inherently unstable (they recycle and lose their state quite often) it's common to use the `.PurgeOnStartup(true)` line after `.MsmqTransport()` in order to flush any messages waiting for the web application in queue during startup.  This is because commonly, messages addressed to a web application are instructions to modify state, but a web application just starting up has no state!  Why process a bunch of commands to "drop cache item X" when we know for a fact our cache is empty?

So to summarize, you can (and in some cases, should) have your web application subscribe to events from other services, dependent upon your business logic, you just have to be careful about how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I know what you are saying.

Basically your web app, which I assume is hosted in IIS, is looking at a database and then displays the results to a user.

You want an business event raised from another service to be sent as a message and to be received into the database, allowing your user to then refresh the page and see the new data.

What you want to do is very reasonable, but you need to stop thinking about your web app subscribing to something.

What you need is another service which receives messages sent by a sender service. When the service receives a message it will write that message into the database.

Then your web app can pick the data up from the database and display it for a user.

The two processes are totally independent. Your web app is hosted in IIS. Your receiver service can be hosted in it's own process. This decouples your web app from the reciever service.

You can use NServiceBus to enable this scenario.

Your sender service becomes a NServiceBus message sender, and your receiver service becomes a NServiceBus message receiver. The easiest way to do this is to host your sender and receiver using the NServiceBus generic host and deploy them out as windows services.